# Elmah Oracle database

Tags: oracle, elmah

I'm trying to use Elmah on one of my recent project.
I'm using an oracle database so I got the oracle [script](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/Oracle) for Elmah, but I'm sure I'm doing something wrong because when I run the scrip I get this error:

[image: Oracle Error]

Any ideas?
Thank for your time!

Comment: you should be able to run the script through sqlplus or a gui tool which gives you which line the error happens on